# Firebase Authentication FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an authentication workflow for my android app. I'm allowing users to sign in with username/password and various OAuth providers. I'm validating emails and password so that, I know the information I'm passing to Firebase is valid. I'm using `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1`

When I execute the following code, I get a callback that says the operation not successful with an error.

```
mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username,password).addOnCompleteListener(this);
```

Callback function or completion listener tells me

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
```

The username I'm passing doesn't exist yet. So, I would assume to see some kind of error stating the **user doesn't exist**. Am I passing something incorrectly or am I assuming incorrectly? I can also see that in the Firebase documentation, the iOS library has a various error codes common to all API methods section where as the Android section doesn't show this. One of these exceptions is `FIRAuthErrorCodeUserNotFound`. So, does that functionality even exists in the Android library?

Comment: I  definitely wouldn't say it states that the user doesn't exist. I think it implies there is something wrong with the connection -> phone is offline, server is down, server didn't respond, etc.

Comment: I am getting the same problem now. does anyone have idea have a solution yet ? Thank you

Comment: I'm getting similar error message

Comment: I'm getting similar error message(2)

Comment: From the answers below, it looks like a default error handler for all unhandled errors. Good work, Google!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It can also happen when google play services are not running. Try to launch play store and check if it is working. If not reboot of device issue.And also compare the google play services using in the project and google play services in the device are same if not update google play services.

This is just a minor but possible case where it gives the exception.

Answer (score 25):

changing from `<form></form>` to `<div></div>` solved this problem:

"A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred in a form element in the HTML. Small bug."

Comment: This did it for me.  I had a form but was handling the button click myself instead of doing a post or anything.

Comment: Solved it.  Thanks.  Any idea why?

Comment: This solved it for me, 3 years after this answer was posted. To echo @danh, does anyone know why?

Comment: Holy cow, this answer from 2016 still solved this for me in 2022. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

1. Reason is Simple ! Check if Device has internet connection.
2. if you have google services enabled
3. phone time settings
4. firebase json file is wrong .cant take client id or google app id or api key

Comment: Thanks for this. My issue was - the physical device I was testing with wasn't connected to the internet.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a (click)="login()" class="nav-link">Login</a>
```

Do not put `href` attribute into tag `a`. It is help to solved my case

Answer (score 3):

If you do this check in form onSumbit handler, you need to preventDefault before sending a request.

This is a snippet (React) that works:

```
class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        };
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        this.handleLoginChange = this.handleLoginChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleLoginChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            email: event.target.value,
            password: this.state.password,
        });
    }

    handlePasswordChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            email: this.state.email,
            password: event.target.value,
        });
    }

    login(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        firebase.auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then(function(user) {
                      window.alert('OK' + user);
                  },
                  function(error) {
                      window.alert('ERR' + error);
                  });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.login}>
                <TextField hintText="login" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleLoginChange} /><br/>
                <TextField hintText="password" type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} /><br/>
                <RaisedButton type="submit" label="Login" primary={true} />
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your AndroidManifest.xml add, it works for me

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: :facepalm .........

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. what solved my problem by clear extra space in API_KEY, so my suggestion is to check your GoogleService-Info.plist for

1. API_KEY is proper (without extra spaces)
2. GOOGLE_APP_ID
3. CLIENT_ID

I think this might help you

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem fixing the date of my cell phone were one year late, when I fixed the date, everything worked well again and the error disappear, I hopping this help you

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem after searching a lot i got the solution, In my case it was happening due to the restriction of background data.

---

If you turn off background data of Google Service Framework. Check & turn on it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your rewrites in `firebase.json`, make sure you don't rewrite auth provider url `/__/`

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "!/__/**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**/!(*.js|*.html|*.css|*.json|*.svg|*.png|*.jpg|*.jpeg)",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Also it could be service worker problem. See https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/290

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue is due to mismatch versions of dependencies, then I have changed dependencies like below

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:+'
```

then its started working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Can also happen if your `authDomain` is set improperly in your firebase keys for web projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem accessing firebase. In my case, the problem was that I was doing this on a real device via the debugger. Once I ran the code "normally" the error vanished. So, it might be helpful to check whether the debugger is getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Genymotion, it could be that you did not activate Open Gapps (in the top right corner)

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same error and there are sometimes very small things which we forget
Like -> Turn On Internet as

```
 com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred
```

**This is FirebaseNetwordException**
there might be case when Host is not Reachabe like mentioned above so check you connectivity

aslo check weather you have provided Internet Permissions in Manifest or not.

hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It could be a million things my advice based on my experience is check the firebase logs and work the problem from there.

In my case I was hitting the endpoint successfully but it was generating a catch error because of an invalid variable **rowsCompany** on the res.json({...response...} )

[image]

Comment: how does one see these logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason might be, that the clients that are getting this error are sending request from China, because all URLs such as *.google.com and *.googleapis.com are blocked in China.

Apparently Firebase has a China service at https://firebase.google.cn, but I didn't have chance to check it out yet. You can also read more on this in this Stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42620514/1372783