# Can firebase be used as a database in China now

Tags: firebase

I am now developing a social application. But recently I noticed that Firebase is blocked in China. So I want to make sure whether firebase can be used in China?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

*** EDIT 24 January 2020 ***

Some of the information here might be out of date.
Firebase has a China service at https://firebase.google.cn/ which is not blocked in the PRC. (Thanks to @c-an for bringing this up.)
That said, *.google.com and *.googleapis.com **are** still blocked in China. I'll change/update this as I get more information.

**Original Answer**

For now Firebase is blocked and can't be used in China, along with other Google services, because the PRC has [blocked](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/mkyeTKU839Q) all URIs with *.google.com and *.googleapis.com.

This also means, for example, that the Play app store can't be accessed from China. If you don't know what's going on between Google and the PRC, [here's a primer](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2016/01/why-google-quit-china-and-why-its-heading-back/424482/).

Also, according to Chinese law, user data of Chinese citizens must be stored inside of the PRC. You might be able to get away with only addressing this once you have a significant number of users, but the trend has been for the CCP to crack down more and more on foreign information, even busting VPNs and [declaring them illegal](http://www.scmp.com/news/china/policies-politics/article/2064587/chinas-move-clean-vpns-and-strengthen-great-firewall) despite complaints of academics who say that they need, you know, real information.

As we're now in the run-up to the 19th Party Congress this autumn, we can expect the situation to get worse before it gets better.  Maybe 2018 will leave room for relaxation?

For now, very sadly, forget anything Google in China, and be prepared to store user data of PRC citizens on servers located inside the Great Firewall. Also be prepared for seemingly random degradations of your service within China, or to be blocked altogether, along with [these other blocked services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websites_blocked_in_mainland_China).

**Update** 2017-11-23:  The 19th Party Congress has come and gone and, if anything, Google services look less likely than ever to become available in China. The great firewall is likely to continue to be strengthened as the Chinese Communist Party extends its role into corporations, and foreign firms are generally disadvantaged.

**Update** 2018-08-05: Google plans to open a censored version of its search in China, [according to leaked documents](https://theintercept.com/2018/08/01/google-china-search-engine-censorship/).  It seems reasonable to assume that if a censored Google Search becomes available in the PRC, then Firebase and other Google Cloud products may as well. The censored search plan, code-named Dragonfly, has reportedly been in the works since December 2017, possibly a result of meetings that month between Google CEO Sundar Pichai and an unnamed top Chinese official when [they met at the World Internet Conference in Wuzhen, China](https://qz.com/1145637/2017-world-internet-conference-tim-cook-and-sundar-pichais-surprise-remarks/), where PRC General Secretary and President Xi Jinping gave a speech.

**Update** 2018-12-23: It appears that [Google's Project Dragonfly is now on hold if not outright abandoned](https://theintercept.com/2018/12/17/google-china-censored-search-engine-2/). This implies that the outlook for Firebase in China has worsened.

Comment: Do you know any way to temporarily enable users to access Firebase related services there? For example, can we route the Firebase requests trough our servers or can we include a VPN like feature in the applications itself?
I'll drop Firebase in the future, but I'm looking for a fast solution for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Sad to drop Firebase because of this, right? Routing through other servers outside of China first should do it. I'd imagine that even just, say, Firebase > AWS Seoul > Chinese end user should do the trick. I'd love to hear how it goes. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! If we can get it working, I'll let you know.

Comment: @Endanke How about your temporarily plan going? I'd like to do it too.

Comment: I just used VPN for the demonstration on my phone, since the target group liked my software, I have to switch to a self-hosted data storage method. Probably we will go with Realm.

Comment: @Mallory-Erik So what do you think is the best alternative in this situation?

Comment: @Darush Your own situation should probably guide you, but generally I'd want to write my own backend and API. If you don't need China initially, you could use Firebase first and then build a non-Firebase version later.

Comment: @Mallory-Erik probably use AWS then.  It makes headache for mobile ap developer.

Comment: @RajuyourPepe Yup, AWS Cognito, etc.

Comment: Can use firebase in China now?

Comment: @EricChong I  haven't seen any indication that things have changed, so I assume you cannot. I read that Google was trying to open some AR services in the PRC on Android phones, I believe by using Chinese partners. The internet has been growing more censored in China, and Xi Jinping's moves to consolidate and extend his power would not seem to bode well. AWS and Azure backends have been getting simpler to use, maybe you can try them.

Comment: I am also in the same dilemma. I am trying to drop Firebase and adopt MongoDB hoping that Mongo Atlas and Stitch would work in China too.

Comment: Why can't you spin up an intermediary domain and use Firebase Java, Python or Nodejs SDK - server-side, so that you just post the username / email / passwd back to your own API and have it return the session data?

Comment: Given this problem of FCM blocked in China which are the best alternatives for sending push notifications in China ? In above comments folks mentioned AWS, Azure. But when I read the AWS docs it mentions using FCM, APNS in-turn for sending push messages. In that case it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you pretty sure that it is blocked? Then, how GA receives data from CN region?

Comment: @c-an This link might interest you: https://mydaytodo.com/chinese-downloads-firebase-itunesconnect-numbers-mismatch/  But if  you can test and find that Firebase is working consistently, please update the answer.^^

Comment: @Malory-Erik how can you explain https://firebase.google.cn/? see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_China and see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websites_blocked_in_mainland_China. As you can see, Firebase is not listed.

Comment: And Chinese can access the URL, you can test here: https://www.comparitech.com/privacy-security-tools/blockedinchina. However, I agree that google is not stable for doing Chinese services.

Comment: @c-an Looks like we need to change the answer to reflect this. google.com and googleapis.com are still blocked, so apparently users/developers outside of China need to access a google.cn domain? Do you know how this is working?

Comment: I have the same question ... I am using tokens generated by the server so can I just change my domain from https://xxxxxxxxxxx-925.firebaseio.com to https://xxxxxxxxxxx-925.firebaseio.cn ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.cn/ is only for documentation

Source: https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/JrVeRE0PHJQ?pli=1

Comment: I just tested and I am able to access my realtime database hosted on the Singapore region in China mainland. No need to modify anything. Whatever works overseas, works in China. Tested in Beijing.

Answer (score 6):

You can build your own Rest API server outside of China, and make the server talks to Firebase rest api endpoints of Realtime db or Authentication, https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database. So you web app talks to your rest api server (accessible from China), and your rest api server talks to Firebase.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is NO :
Using a huge part of Firebase services, I contacted the support, this is the answer :

> I'm glad you are considering Firebase for your project. However, in
> accordance with current U.S. policies, it is not possible to use
> Firebase from within certain countries. For more information about
> these restrictions, please refer to the [U.S. Department of the
> Treasury website](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Pages/Programs.aspx). The current list is of blocked countries is listed
> [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389?hl=en). If you have end-users located within China, it's quite difficult
> to access Firebase there since the use of Firebase requires Google
> Play Services, which most of the devices in China don't have. We
> understand that access to our products has been problematic from
> within mainland China. We believe it may have been caused by
> networking conditions in China, rather than Google's own services.
> Since access to services is determined by the respective country's
> government and they don't report to Google, the [Transparency Report](http://www.google.com/transparencyreport/traffic/) is
> the most authoritative it can be.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested and I am able to access my realtime database hosted on the Singapore region in China mainland. No need to modify anything. Whatever works overseas, works in China. Tested in Beijing.

Comment: Do you need vpn to access Stackoverflow now? I had issue access issues back to few years ago

Answer (score -1):

Facing the same problem, if you are in china, install Astrill VPN and change from openweb to StealthVPN, connect to a server like USA for china one and login to firebase. It will work successfully.