# Firebase analytics in China

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics, great-firewall-of-china

I recently added Firebase analytics to my iOS app and I was wondering if Firebase analytics can track app usage in China? The thing is, we get a lot of downloads from China and tracking app usage in China is pretty important.

Some context, I initially wanted to add Google Analytics but the Google Analytics page for iOS apps redirected me to Firebase and hence I ended up adding Firebase analytics to my app.

Comment: Checkout this answer for more details on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/42620514/4348158

Comment: I had a look at that answer beforeI post this question. That question doesn't cover the topic of Firebase Analytics, I reckon it's only looking at it from a Firebase DB perspective.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, both firebase analytics and fabric are not reporting anything from China

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally have a theory that I am satisfied with and I have written a [blogpost](https://mydaytodo.com/chinese-downloads-firebase-and-itunesconnect/) that I hope can save others some time. The post details my analysis of the situation the includes how the GFW in China works, the OPT-IN nature of App Analytics in iTunes and why some data for Firebase analytics comes through. Yes and the reason we may see some analytics data in Firebase is not because of VPN, it's in part in the nature of how GFW works.

Answer (score -5):

Firebase Analytics should work in China.

Comment: I have official response from the Firebase support team that there is a service disruption in China!