# Task is unsuccessful in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a problem in this code that why every time it is showing registration error after filling the form  and ids are fine but I dont know what is wrong with this code.Errors are here!! how i can fix it.Please help me !! Thanks

```
public class reg2activity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText emailvariable;
EditText passvariable;
Button regvariable;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reg2activity);
    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    emailvariable=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.regemailid);
    passvariable=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.regpassid);
    regvariable=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Regloginid);
    regvariable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            userReg();
        }
    });
}

public void userReg() {
    String emailstring=emailvariable.getText().toString();
    String passstring=passvariable.getText().toString();
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailstring,passstring).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Toast.makeText(reg2activity.this,"Regestration successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(reg2activity.this,"Regestration error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The error message I got is:

```
07-16 14:09:09.281 2780-2780/com.example.avc.homeproject 
 W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
07-16 14:09:09.501 2780-2780/com.example.avc.homeproject W/System.err: 
com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as 
timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvf.zzap(Unknown Source)
    07-16 14:09:09.511 2780-2780/com.example.avc.homeproject W/System.err:     
 at 
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzduh.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvq.zzaq(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvt.onFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvh.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:433)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: When the create user request is not successful, add `task.getException().getMessage()` to your toast to see the reason for failure.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052162/firebase-authentication-firebasenetworkexception-a-network-error-such-as-timeo).

1. In your AndroidManifest.xml add permissions for INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
2. It can also happen when google play services are not running. Try to launch play store and check if it is working. If not reboot of device issue.And also compare the google play services using in the project and google play services in the device are same if not update google play services.
   This is just a minor but possible case where it gives the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The common issues can be

First: Authentication is not enabled so do

```
Enable Email/Password sign-in:
 a. In the Firebase console, open the Auth section.
 b. On the Sign in method tab, enable the Email/password sign-in method and click Save.
```

Second: The email is not valid or password is not Strong enough
e.g

```
Email            Password     Valid
abc@gmail.com    123Ab!         Yes
ab.com           123Ab!         invalid email
abc@gmail.com    12345          weak password
```

Third : don't reuse the same email

and to know more, catch the exception and print it

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailstring,passstring).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Toast.makeText(reg2activity.this,"Regestration successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                task.getException().printStackTrace();
                // add this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                Toast.makeText(reg2activity.this,"Regestration error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Now Errors are mentioned in question

Comment: @Usman make sure you have a stable connection and also update google play services if available, hope you have latest dependencies in gradle file