# Firebase Auth - A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Update**

My app is continuously getting this crash in the live app. There are 100-200 crashes per week. So I am starting a bounty on this question. If someone has solved it. Please help.

However, 99% of users are crash-free. These crashes may be affecting my app's repo on the play-store. so if I don't get the solution, then I will finally remove this feature to login by email/password in FirebaseAuth :/

**Problem:**

I got many crashes (295 crashes from 249 users) in the Android app Firebase Auth Login. 1-2% of users trying to log in by email-password are getting this crash. I researched for this error and got the hint that this occurs when play-service is not running by [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42542855/6891563)

FYI google/Facebook auth is running perfectly. This issue is in log in via email-password only.

**What I have tried?**

I tried to put a try-catch block on the login method. and tried to catch this exception. As the solution, I thought to show a dialog about informing users that the play service is not running. And he can manually open play-store to start play-service, and then visit back this.

But as I can see on Fabric, crashes never come to catch block, and the app crashes when this exception occurs. Because this error is thrown in FirebaseAuth SDK.

**What is needed?**

First I want to be sure about the reason for this exception. If this occurs due to the play service not running, then I want to show the user a dialog. Which never shows currently, and it crashes after the below exception.

```
Fatal Exception: com.google.android.gms.g.f: com.google.firebase.e: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source)
       at com.startech.dreamteam11.app.activities.ActivityLogin.tryLogin(Unknown Source)
       at com.startech.dreamteam11.app.activities.ActivityLogin.lambda$-wlX6lv_j3Q0nUN9OuqzHS7ZGP4(Unknown Source)
       at com.startech.dreamteam11.app.activities.-$$Lambda$ActivityLogin$-wlX6lv_j3Q0nUN9OuqzHS7ZGP4.onComplete(lambda)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

**Code**

```html
    private void loginViaEmailPassword(String email, String pass) {
        showProgressBar();
        try {
             // check if user is registered. then try login
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                SignInMethodQueryResult result = task.getResult();
                if (task.isSuccessful() && result != null && result.getSignInMethods() != null && result.getSignInMethods().size() > 0) {
                    // user is registered, now try login
                    tryLogIn(email, pass, new OnFireBaseLogin() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FirebaseUser user) {
                            // check if email is verified, if not send verification email.
                            if (user.isEmailVerified()) {
                                // user is verified, redirect to main screen
                                startMainActivity();
                            } else {
                                sendVerificationEmail(user, task1 -> {
                                    hideProgressBar();
                                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                    if (task1.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Utilities.getInstance().showDialog(ActivityLogin.this, getString(R.string.sent_verification_email), getString(R.string.msg_sent_verification_email), (dialog, which) -> {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        errorMessage(getString(R.string.msg_error_sending_email));
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(int error, @Nullable Throwable exception) {
                            hideProgressBar();
                            assert exception != null;
                            {
                                App.getInstance().logException(new Exception(exception), getClass());
                                errorMessage(exception.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    hideProgressBar();
                    errorMessage(getString(R.string.msg_email_not_registered));
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            hideProgressBar();
            App.getInstance().logException(e, getClass(), true);
            Utilities.getInstance().showDialog(this, getString(R.string.some_error_occurred), getString(R.string.msg_fail_login_play_service)).show();
        }
    }
```

```html
    public void tryLogIn(String email, String pass) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (task.isSuccessful() && currentUser != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken:success", task.getException());
                    successResponse(currentUser);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken:failure", task.getException());
                    errorResponse(0, task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen please have a look on issue.

Comment: Nothing to do with GCP status last week, maybe?
https://status.cloud.google.com/

Comment: @Racu did not get you.

Comment: Since I saw network error in your logcat, thought that maybe was related to outages of GCP about three days ago. But if you still have those issues maybe it's unrelated to that. 
I had some issues related to those outages during that period.

Comment: @Racu Yes, I can see crashes in last 24 hour also.

Comment: Sorry, thought that might be related.

Comment: @Racu thanks for your help :)

Comment: This is exactly what happens to my app when I start it in Airplane Mode. Did you check that?

Comment: @JoaquinIurchuk check if task is successful in response and check error codes in official documents, you will get your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Validation.loginValidation(edtEmail, edtPass)) {
                    loginFirebase(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPass.getText().toString(), firebaseAuth);
                }
            }
        });




public void loginFirebase(String email, String pass, FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait.....");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Processing....");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        (firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DrawerMain.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    edtEmail.setText("");
                    edtPass.setText("");
                } else {
                    Log.e("Error", task.getException().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope that can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: What is different in this code? You are using same way to login. Same methods call. By the way, my code works well too. Just it gets crash in 1% cases.

Comment: You are use many if and else condition so, i think that become complicated so error was generated.

Comment: And It can also happen when google play services are not running. Try to launch play store and check if it is working. If not reboot of device issue.And also compare the google play services using in the project and google play services in the device are same if not update google play services.

This is just a minor but possible case where it gives the exception.

Comment: For your first comment - I tried to handle this exception by any chance. So you see if else. This is not a reason, that many `if-else` occurs an error.

Comment: For 2nd comment - I already coded for same reason (play-service not running). But that seems not working. so I asked question sir.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `addOnCompleteListener`, you always need to check if the `task` is successful.

Try the follow,

```
somethingTask().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "somethingTask:ERROR", task.getException());
        return;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "somethingTask:SUCCESS");
    // Now we are logged in, let's write next code!
}
```

I'm writing this answer based on your error stack trace which is throwing the error from `getResult` in the `tryLogin` method.

**+** You won't catch the exception like that kind of way, since `addOnCompleteListener` is an `asynchronous` method.

Comment: Thank you for help. Did you check my cod? I am checking `task.isSuccessFull()` in my code.

Comment: @Khemraj I checked your code, and your error stack trace and provided code looks slightly different. Your error has `tryLogin`, but the code has `tryLogIn`, and where is `OnFireBaseLogin` definition?

Comment: @Khemraj Especially, you are using `getResult` outside of `isSuccessful` checking method. I recommend you to use `getResult` only if the task is successful.

Comment: `OnFireBaseLogin` is an interface callback, I removed it to make question short and easy.

Comment: Oh, how did I miss it. perhaps this is the issue. I should move `getResult()` after checking `task.isSuccessful()`. I will try it.

Comment: I did not get a chance to test this. But I think this is more logical answer. So I am awarding this bounty to you. :)