# Firebase Network Issue?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

So I'm currently designing an App and firstly making a login page, I so far got up to login/registering users, however, every time I try to login I get a network error and I can't tell if it's the code or Google as I am using google authentication services.

I've followed tutorials on setting up the firebase to my pubspec and build but it still doesn't seem to work.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

    class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _LoginPageState();
    }

    enum FormType {
      login,
      register
    }

    class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

      final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

      String _email;
      String _password;
      FormType _formType = FormType.login;
      String _authHint = '';

      bool validateAndSave() {
        final form = formKey.currentState;
        if(form.validate()){
          form.save();
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

      void validateAndSumbit() async {
      if (validateAndSave()) {
        try {
          if(_formType == FormType.login) {
      FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)) as FirebaseUser;
      print('Signed in: ${user.uid}');
        } else {
          FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)) as FirebaseUser;
          print('Registered user: ${user.uid}');
          }
        }
        catch (e) {
          print('Error: $e');
        }
      }
    }

      void moveToRegister() {
        formKey.currentState.reset();
        setState(() {
          _formType = FormType.register;
        });
      }

      void moveToLogin() {
        setState(() {
          _formType = FormType.login;
        });
      }

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title:  new Text('Car Parking App'),
            ),
            body: new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: new Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: new Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: buildInputs() + buildSubmitButtons(),
                ),
              ),
            )
          );
        }

        List<Widget> buildInputs() {
          return [
        new TextFormField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
          validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'t be empty' : null,
          onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
          ),
        new TextFormField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
          obscureText: true,
          validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Password can\'t be empty' : null,
          onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
          ),
          ];
        }

        List<Widget> buildSubmitButtons() {
          if (_formType == FormType.login) {
          return [
                  new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text('Login', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
            onPressed: validateAndSumbit,
          ),
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text('Create an Account', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
            onPressed: moveToRegister,
          )
          ];
        } else {
                return [
                  new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text('Create an Account', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
            onPressed: validateAndSumbit,
          ),
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text('Already have an account? Login', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
            onPressed: moveToLogin,
          )
          ];
        }
        }
    }
```

V/AudioManager(27253): playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
V/AudioManager(27253): querySoundEffectsEnabled...
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(27253): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@744c74e
W/DynamiteModule(27253): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth(27253): [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth(27253): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
I/flutter (27253): Error: PlatformException(ERROR_NETWORK_REQUEST_FAILED, A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred., null)

Comment: Too many possibility. please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052162/firebase-authentication-firebasenetworkexception-a-network-error-such-as-timeo . and does your include <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/> in your  AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: please let me know your test result. thanks.

Comment: After entering this into the manifest.xml I am now getting an error about my API key not being valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue, the API key was different in the google-services file compared to the website API key, once I changed that it worked fine.