# FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

- Android Studio version: 3.6.3
- Firebase Component: Auth
- Component version: 19.4.0

I've an android app in production with over 500k downloads on google play and some users (i dont know exactly why) have this error when logging in...

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host)
       at com.tomatedigital.giveawaymaster.task.LoginTask.lambda$firebaseAuth$1(LoginTask.java:249)
       at com.tomatedigital.giveawaymaster.task.-$$Lambda$LoginTask$p6eSSF8vZ2BATwhlFttcJl8qT-w.onComplete(-.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(zzi.java:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

there is no an easy correlation between these users, different android versions, different phone models....

i found this old issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/384 but seems that someone in firebase team just trew it under the carpet instead of solving it (very common there)

the error is happening in real devices in production,
I've a small chat embebed in the app and some users with problem come to support, ive asked to reinstall the app but they keep error... also it is not an INTERNET CONNECTION problem because people are talking to me in an online chat and having the problem in the same time

crashlytics show it is happening in 1% of sessions...

Relevant Code:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCustomToken(token).addOnCompleteListener(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("new firebase token successfully authenticated");
                } else {
                    App.shouldNeverHappen(new RuntimeException(task.getException().getMessage() + " data: " + sb.toString()));
                    this.exception = task.getException();
                }

});

//token is generated in my Firebase cloud functions as
auth.createCustomToken(uid).then(function(customToken) {
        res.status(200).send(customToken);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error creating custom token:" + JSON.stringify(error));
        res.status(200).json({
            e: error
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you confirm that they are not using a proxy app such as VPNs, or using proxy behind network? and [it can also happen when google play services are not running.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42542855/4729203)

Answer (score 0):

this issue can occur due to a few reasons

1. **LACK OF PERMISSIONS**
2. **PLAY SERVICES NOT RUNNING OR FREEZED OR OUTDATED (E.G ON HUAWEI  OR XIAOMI DEVICES)**

Have a look at running services before launching the application if the services are frozen then unfreeze them and if they are outdated then update them and run the application again after a restart

3. **INCORRECT DATE & TIME**

It might also occur if the date of the device is not correct, if the date is not correct then correct it

4. **Also occur on Mobile Data because the sometimes default data configurations have a proxy, try running on wifi to diagnose the error**

Comment: personal experience with the issue of mobile data, and lack of permissions, but have no solid proof because I was unable to mimic the error, after reading the  Play services not available or not running can be found on the stack overflow question, Also read that error occured deue to the inaccurate time and date, "accoring to the solutions on stackoverflow"

Comment: to be honest, these were the reasons people are having crashes, but no one knows what the actual reason is

Answer (score -1):

Go to Project >> andriod >> right click and open new terminal in directory
run command 'gradlew signingReport' and copy the SHA-1 key. Now open
Firebase console >> project settings >> add fingerprint
paste the SHA-1 key int here.